# How do I make Fluxus/Frisbee work?

Tags: macos, scheme, racket

I'm running the latest downloadable mac version of Fluxus from the official site.

When I do

```
(require fluxus-017/frisbee)
```

It gives me:

> default-load-handler: cannot open
>   input file:
>   "/Applications/Visual/Fluxus/Fluxus.app/Contents/Resources/collects/frtime/list.ss"
>   (No such file or directory; errno=2)

I've tried this fix http://www.mail-archive.com/fluxus@lists.pawfal.org/msg00922.html
but now the Fluxus hangs after requiring frisbee.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: It's probably best to ask on the mailing list...

Comment: I've asked both here and on the mailing list. :)

Comment: I've got an answer from the mail-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more up-to-date binary available at 
http://fluxus.mndl.hu/fluxus-0.17-1.20110513git.mac_intel.10.5.dmg

It works!